# change menu key behaviour for xfce-terminal

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, xfce

I use the menu key a lot in my text editor bindings, but that does not work in terminal mode, because the xfce-terminal I use responds to menu button by opening the context menu.

So I'd like to change that behaviour for the terminal, without remapping the menu key if possible.

But I really don't know where to start.

Answer (score 0):

According to [xfce4-terminal documentation](https://docs.xfce.org/apps/terminal/start), keyboard shortcuts can be configured by editing your `~/.config/xfce4/terminal/accels.scm` file.

For example, I assigned the Menu key to execute the `Set Title...` action by changing the line

```
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/terminal-window/set-title" "<Primary><Shift>s")
```

to

```
(gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/terminal-window/set-title" "Menu")
```

*Note:* The terminal needs to be restarted for changes in `accels.scm` to take effect.

Comment: this does not answer the question, as the menu key is not explicitly mapped in that config file